# send sms and notification without internet while the app requires internet to function?

Tags: android, database

If my app require internet connection for authentication and am storing information that is supposed to send an SMS to client upon the time I specify reaches..can the app send the SMS without the internet connection??

Comment: Please write your requirement in detail. Your detail is not saying what type of SMS you are using so that it needs internet. It would be good if you mention related components in detail.

Comment: if your app send request to server and server sends the message then internet connection is required.

Comment: suppose you designed in a way that you send SMS from Android client without communicating with the server, it is possible.

Comment: thanks namu I wanted it to send SMS on information stored on phone and there after delete  the information on phone and update it to the server to free memory.but keeping in mind it can send information inform of SMS without the internet connection.